# How to setstate for the dynamic checkboxes in a loop in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, state

I am loading checkboxes in a loop. I have difficulties in setting the states for the dynamic checkboxes.

I am loading checkboxes in a loop. I need to set the state of the checkboxes to make them work. when I set the state every checkbox gets checked so please give me a solution

**Component Initialization**

```
const ChildComponent = props =>
  <div key={"comp" + props.number} className="relay-team-list">
      <div className="read-more">
          <a href="#">Team {props.number} - Click to Rename</a>
      </div>
      {
          props.members_arr.length > 0 ? (
              props.members_arr.map((member, i) =>
                  member.position === props.number ? (
                      <div key={"members" + i} className="columns is-mobile list-item" id={"member" + props.number}>
                          <div className="column is-one-third">
                              <img src={require('../images/user.png')} />
                          </div>
                          <div className="column txt-mid-grey relay-team-list-text">
                              <p>{member.members_arr.member_name}</p>
                              <p></p>
                              <span className="check-icon"><input type="checkbox" value="checkedB"
                                  checked={this.state.enabledCheckBox + i}
                                  label={{ children: 'cardreader' + i }}
                                  onChange={this.passMemberID}
                              /></span>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                  ) : ''
              )
          ) : ''
      }
  </div>;
```

**The Function**

```
passMemberID = () => {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    enabledCheckBox: !prevState.enabledCheckBox
  }), () => console.log(this.state.enabledCheckBox))
}
```

**Constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    enabledCheckBox: false,
  }
}
```

I need to have different states to every checkbox so I can click them one by one now all are getting checked at once

Comment: It's the best to use an array in your state: `this.state = {enabledCheckedBoxes: []}` and handle each checkbox by it's index: `passMemberID = (index) => () => {yourlogic}`. And in your UI call the `passMemberID` by the index of the checkbox. You could init the array after mounting the component. Further, [here is a quick recommendation for cleaning your code](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: @Navid you mean in UI set as {()=>this.passMemberID(i)} like this?

Comment: @Navid I am new to react and studying alone could you please give me some code example

Comment: @Navid thanks for the idea you have given and I have fixed the code to the standard level using the link you have given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    checkBoxObj: {}
  };
}
```

Component:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
     checked = {this.state.checkBoxObj[i] || false}
     onChange={() => this.passMemberID(i)}
/>
```

Function:

```
passMemberID = (i) => {
  this.setState({
    checkBoxObj: {
      ...this.state.checkBoxObj, ...{[i]: !this.state.checkBoxObj[i]}
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This `value="checkedB"` is not needed

Comment: @MorloMbakop is right. value and label are not necessary at all. I just put them from the questions. I am making an edit to remove then.

Comment: @MorloMbakop I am using the value for a different validation and thanks guys I finally found a way to do it, it is a bit similar to Mahanta's code but I used an array instead of the object